# Batch window's colors are screwd up by Node.js and related commandline services

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, colors, node.js

I run node.js from a batch file and whenever some command that has colorful output it screws up my batch window's default colors.

[image]

^ Here it's [debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) that does it, but any command that has colored output does it.

And even though the services that make *only* the output ***text*** colorful, they somehow mess up my background color as well.

Is there a way to prevent my batch window from getting its colors changed?